# Eigenvalues and vectors of a projection matrix conjugated by another projection

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there any good way to characterize the eigenvalues / eigenvectors of $PQP$, where $P, Q$ are both orthogonal projection matrices? There are trivial cases when the spaces onto which $P,Q$ project are either orthogonal (in which case the $PQP = 0$) or when $\mathcal{C}(P) = A + B$, $\mathcal{C}(Q) = A + C$, $B\perp C$ (in which case the $PQP$ becomes a projection onto $A$). However, in general, $PQP$ may not even be a projection matrix. Can we still characterize its eigenvalues / vectors?